# What is a 'Destructured Imported Asset'?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

> Consider listing destructured imported assets alphabetically.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#03-06

What is a 'destructured imported asset'?

Code that is supposed to show an example (I don't know which one, if any, is a 'destructured imported asset'):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Hero } from './hero.model';
import { ExceptionService, SpinnerService, ToastService } from '../../core';
```

Comment: Those people don't know what they're talking about. Those are *named import*, and have nothing to do with destructuring.

Comment: @Bergi: Yea, that's what confused me, I am familiar with the import syntax (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), but that name threw me off.

Comment: Actually it's possible that "import destructuring" is a TypeScript-specific phrase. Not sure what [their current stance on ES6 modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242) is. Notice there's (not) a [separate styleguide for plain JavaScript](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/style-guide.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it further, just wanted to make sure it wasn't something absolutely obvious.